# Delete Repeated Consecutive Cells which ONLY include specific value (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

I have a very specific thing I need Matlab to do, and I'm not really sure how to go about doing it.

Here is an example of what I'm working with:

```
'B4,9(55)'
'B4,9(55)'
'B2,16,25(99)'
'B2,16,25(99)'
'B17,21,28,29(46)'
'B4,10(56)'
'B4,10(56)'
'B2,15,25(99)'
'B17,20,27,29(45)'
```

I need a script that will delete consecutive, duplicate entries, but *only* if it contains a certain string (i.e., 52, 55, and 56). Duplicate entries with (99) should not be deleted. So, what I would want to end up with would be this:

```
'B4,9(55)'
'B2,16,25(99)'
'B2,16,25(99)'
'B17,21,28,29(46)'
'B4,10(56)'
'B2,15,25(99)'
'B17,20,27,29(45)'
```

Is this possible?

---

EDIT: Some greater context...
I work in an EEG lab and we use Matlab to analyze our data. Upon opening Matlab, I run 'eeglab'. I then open a set file. I run a script that creates a list of EEG events, and also removes certain event types that I don't want.

```
%create a list of events
justevents = {EEG.event.type};

%delete the 201-203s
justevents(strcmp(justevents,'201'))=[];
justevents(strcmp(justevents,'202'))=[];
justevents(strcmp(justevents,'203'))=[];

%delete the 101-130s
justevents(strcmp(justevents,'101'))=[];
justevents(strcmp(justevents,'102'))=[];
justevents(strcmp(justevents,'103'))=[];
justevents(strcmp(justevents,'104'))=[];
justevents(strcmp(justevents,'105'))=[];
```

(This goes all the way up to 130)

Then I run the code Suever gave me, but it deletes the 52, 55, and 56 events...

Here is a bigger chunk of example data, including what is removed in the code I included above. I wasn't sure how to format it correctly, but this is the Matlab output...

```
mycell = { ...

'B1,12,25(99)'    '201'    '101'    'B18,23,27,29(45)'    'B3,6(55)' ...
'B3,6(55)'    'B2,16,25(99)'    '201'    '102'    'B17,21,28,29(46)' ...
'B4,10(56)'    'B4,10(56)'    'B1,13,25(99)'    '201'    '201'    '103' ...
'B18,24,28,29(46)'    'B3,7(56)'    'B3,7(56)'    'B2,14,25(99)'    '201' ...
'104'    'B17,19,26,29(42)'    'B4,8(52)'    'B4,8(52)'    'B1,13,25(99)' ...
'201'    '105'    'B18,24,28,29(46)'    'B3,7(56)'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this problem is to first find all duplicate strings and assign an index to each unique string. You can easily do this using the second output of `ismember`.

```
[~, unique_ind] = ismember(mycell, mycell);
```

We can then identify *consecutive* duplicates by finding where we have series of the same index value. We can check this by looking to see if the difference is zero.

```
consec_dupes = [false, diff(unique_ind) == 0];
```

Then we can look at each of these cases where we had repeated values and see if they meet the criteria by using regular expressions. The following will be `true` if 53, 55, or 56 is found in the string and `false` otherwise.

```
ismatch = ~cellfun(@isempty, regexp(mycell(consec_dupes), '\(52|55|56\)'));
```

Now we want to ignore all consecutive duplicates that do not match the specified numbers. To do so, we can now set all of the `consec_dupes` values that *didn't* match to `false`.

```
consec_dupes(consec_dupes) = ismatch;
```

Now we just remove these consecutive duplicates that match from your original cell array.

```
mycell(consec_dupes) = [];
```

## Summary

So bringing all of that together into a single chunk of code:

```
[~, unique_ind] = ismember(mycell, mycell);
consec_dupes = [false, diff(unique_ind) == 0];
ismatch = ~cellfun(@isempty, regexp(mycell(consec_dupes), '\(52|55|56\)'));
consec_dupes(consec_dupes) = ismatch;
mycell(consec_dupes) = [];
```

Applying this on your sample data we get the following:

```
'B1,12,25(99)'
'201'
'101'
'B18,23,27,29(45)'
'B3,6(55)'
'B2,16,25(99)'
'201'
'102'
'B17,21,28,29(46)'
'B4,10(56)'
'B1,13,25(99)'
'201'
'201'
'103'
'B18,24,28,29(46)'
'B3,7(56)'
'B2,14,25(99)'
'201'
'104'
'B17,19,26,29(42)'
'B4,8(52)'
'B1,13,25(99)'
'201'
'105'
'B18,24,28,29(46)'
'B3,7(56)'
```

Comment: I think this solution is very close to working, I appreciate your help! It works perfectly when I test the example dataset I included here. However, when I test it in context of my data, the code deletes all cells with 52, 55, and 56 in them. Any idea why? The example dataset I included is taken directly from a data file produced in my lab, so I don't quite understand why it removes all 52,55, and 56 cases instead of duplicates

Comment: @ChristieSmith Hmmm I can't reproduce that. Can you post some example data in your original question that would trigger this?

Comment: @ChristieSmith Also be sure that you've copied *all* the lines. The `toremove(inds(aind)) = false` line being omitted would definitely cause the problem you mention

Comment: `toremove(inds(aind)) = false` is definitely in there :( I've included context for the data in my original post - please let me know if I need to add anything else! I'll be adding in a greater chunk of data shortly, once I format it for stackoverflow correctly...

Comment: Also, justevents gives a matrix that is 1x514. When testing your code, I did `data = transpose(justevents)` to get it to match up with the format of the example dataset, but it still deletes the 52,55,56 events.

Comment: @ChristieSmith Yea if you can just post some of the offending lines that would be good. Also is it possible that they *are* actually duplicates? It may just be that they aren't exactly one after another

Comment: Added a larger chunk of data. When testing step-wise through your code in the greater context of lab data, aind only retrieves six numbers that I'm not sure what they mean, and toremove remains unchanged from hasmatch, whereas when I test your code using my original example dataset (the small one, where the code worked), toremove has differences between hasmatch. I think the issue may be coming from aind?

Comment: @ChristieSmith I posted the results when I ran your updated dataset and it looks ok. What version of MATLAB are you using?

Comment: Matlab R2012B. I tested it with the updated partial dataset (1x30) and it worked for me as well, but when I copy the entire dataset (1x514) and run the code in matlab without EEGlab (I thought maybe that was the problem) I get the same issue. Is it possible that the dataset is too big? What does `aind` do?

Comment: @ChristieSmith the size of the dataset should not matter. If you want you could post the whole list on pastebin.com and link it here and I can take a look. `aind` should be the indices of `data(hasmatch)` that should be kept.

Comment: @ChristieSmith I just realized that you only wanted *consecutive* duplicates removed. I have completely updated my answer to reflect this. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: That worked perfectly!!! Thank you so much for your help, and the in-depth explanation as well. I sincerely appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to put your strings in a cell.

```
cell = {'B4,9(55)',
'B4,9(55)',
'B2,16,25(99)',
'B2,16,25(99)',
'B17,21,28,29(46)',
'B4,10(56)',
'B4,10(56)',
'B2,15,25(99)',
'B17,20,27,29(45)'};
```

Then, and this is only one option, you can select your data by combining two index.

```
[~,index1] = unique(cell); %find the uniques strings.
index2 = find(cellfun(@isempty,strfind(cell,'99'))==0); %find the string that contains '99'
index = unique([index1;index2]);

mycell = cell(sort(index))
```

Comment: I believe the OP wanted to specify which items to remove not necessarily which items to *exclude*.